# Setting nShadowDetection and fTau for BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 in OpenCV 2.4

Tags: opencv

I am using BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 to extract foreground and I need to set the values 
nShadowDetection=0 and fTau=0.5 to remove shadows.

```
   BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg_model;//(100, 3, 0.3, 5);             
   bg_model.set("bShadowDetection",true);
   bg_model.set("nShadowDetection",0); 
   bg_model.set("fTau",0.5);
```

but it looks like I cannot set nShadowDetection and fTau in OpenCV 2.4 and later because they are Protected and it gives me an error when I run it.

```
bg_model.nShadowDetection=0;
```

doesn't even compile because member is protected.

Answer (score 1):

Try setInt, setDouble and setBool, they are working fine for me

```
bg_model.setInt("nmixtures", 3);

bg_model.setBool("detectShadows", false);

bg_model.setDouble("fTau", 0.5);
```

Best!